# Except error for a name

Tags: python, exception

I have a problem with a program I am making to do with an arithmetic quiz.when I enter a name the quiz should print the welcome message however if I enter a blank or a number then the programme should loop the question but tell the user that they have made an error. I used the try statement and the NameError statement to try and resolve this problem but when I use the function "except" and run it in idle it says that I have an invalid syntax.

here is the code i am trying to fix:

```
import random 
while True:
    try:
        UserName = input("What is your name:")
        except NameError:
            print ("The answer given does not compute!! Try again")
            continue
        else:
            break

        print(UserName," welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz.")
```

I have edited the code for the program, but still when I try to run it in Idle it highlights except and then says invalid syntax.

Comment: Your except is on the wrong indentation level

Comment: Can you add the error message? It looks like `except NameError:` is not aligned properly, at least in your example, it should be aligned with the try: statement it corresponds to.

Comment: @Natecat I have moved the indentation to the right place but I still get an error . Thanks

Comment: @super123 what error, and update your OP

Comment: @busfault I have aligned the code properly but still not able to get it to work it just says that except is an invalid syntax

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent in the loop? An empty string?

Comment: @super123 I am not as familiar with Python3, and I assume it is with the `print(...)` format, but can you have a space between `print` and `(...)`
edit:"Though, that is not likely the issue since it is after the except.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking user for input until they give valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @cricket_007 If the use enters a blank input for the name it should loop the question again.

Comment: @busfault Certainly can.

Comment: @busfault when I run the code and put  a blank input it shows the welcome message and does not loop the question?

Comment: @super123 That is because input isn't raising and exception.
try running it from the interpreter. does  `>>> UserName = input("What is your name:")` give you a NameError exception when you just press enter? or enter a number? this is unless, `input` is some other function that you have defined that raises a NameError?

Comment: A NameError has nothing to do with whether the input is a valid name of a human being. It indicates that a variable lookup has found no value for the variable. If you're getting such errors out of an `input` call, you're on Python 2 and you should be using `raw_input`. Python 2's `input` is essentially never a good idea.

Comment: @user2357112 im on python3

Comment: @super123: Then that line can't raise a NameError. If you want to validate the name entered, you have to check the conditions you're interested in manually.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `try-except` to check for an empty string

```
while True:
    UserName = input("What is your name:")
    if not UserName:
        print("The answer given does not compute!! Try again")
        continue
    else:
        break
print(UserName," welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz.")
```

Comment: is there a way to make it so that if there was a blank space error or  digit it would loop the question.@cricket_007

Comment: I understand what you mean now so if the value checking is empty you don't use the try function @cricket_007

Comment: For a digit, you could use `if UserName.isdigit()` to check if something more than spaces was entered you could check `if UserName.strip()`

Comment: Under stood do you know anybooks that have this info inside them please @cricket_007

Comment: Don't know any books. All the python I learned was from reading the Python documentation online.

Comment: when i use the .strip() and enter letters it loops the question

Comment: Is there another way to stop the input of symbols with affecting the string input @cricket_007

Comment: You could try `UserName.isalpha()` to check for all alphabetical characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111057/discussion-between-super123-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 1):

This is what the proper indentation should be for the `try: except: else:` block

```
import random 
while True:
    try:
        UserName = input("What is your name:")
    except NameError: 
        print("The answer given does not compute!! Try again")
        continue
    else:
        break
print(UserName," welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz.")
```

caveat (thanks cricket_007) this loop will never end. I had meant this comment to show how the `try:` indentation should have been for the OP.

Comment: This is the correct indentation, but the loop never exits

Comment: @cricket_007 I had meant it to only show what the indentation should be like for the OP. I guess I should have elaborated a little :-) thanks!